# ''BuiltIn' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, encoding, itext7, pdftotext

I am converting a PDF to Text using 'iText.PdfTextExtractor' and I am receiving this error ONLY on some of the pdf pages I am trying to convert:

> 'BuiltIn' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. (Parameter 'name')

I've tried adding the following code before opening the file stream, but I am still receiving the error:

```
System.Text.EncodingProvider provider = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(provider);
```

Here is my code:

```
public void ExtractFromPdf(string pdfFile, ClaimInfo claimInfo, string memberId)
{
    System.Text.EncodingProvider provider = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
    Encoding.RegisterProvider(provider);

    PdfReader pdfRead = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfRead);

    for (int page = 1; page < pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
    {
        string convertToText = PdfToText(pdfDoc, page);
    }
}

private string PdfToText(PdfDocument pdfDoc, int pageNo)
{
    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
    return PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(pageNo), strategy);
}
```

The error occurs at `return PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(pageNo), strategy);`

I've tried looking everywhere and it seems that 'BuiltIn' is a built in encoding name that I don't know how to find. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but I don't see you selecting an encoding. Are you missing a reference to ` Encoding.UTF8` ?

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? This sounds like an error in the pdf file.

Comment: @afarrag That's because I'm not sure which encoding to select since the unsupported encoding is 'BuiltIn'. Please let me know if I'm going about this correctly

Comment: @mkl Sorry the pdf contains sensitive information. Is there a way to detect the type of encoding on a pdf? A 'BuiltIn' encoding is ambiguous to me

Comment: I hope you find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61466845/itext7-pdftextextractor-gettextfrompage-standardencoding-is-not-a-supported-e).

Comment: @afarrag Hi I've already seen that post and it helped me a little bit. I appreciate the effort to send me resources though